# Add twig function to Craft CMS

Tags: twig, content-management-system, craftcms

How can I add a custom twig function to Craft CMS version 3?

Twig outlines how to add a function but not sure how to apply to Craft.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#functions

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$function = new Twig_Function('function_name', function () {
    // ...
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

Comment: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/how-do-i-create-a-custom-twig-extension-which-includes-third-party-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Do I need to create a plugin to add a twig function?

Comment: If you are able to pinpoint the `twig` instance in `craftcms` you could go with adding one function. But i'm thinkng you are better off with going with the longer way. It will be easier in the longrun when u need to add more than one filter/function